# How do I convert GBK to UTF8 with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, gbk

I want to load some text from other site which the content is GBK encoded, but my site is UTF8.

Is there anyway by which I can convert these GBK text into UTF8 for display?

For some reasons I can only use JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.1kjs.com/lib/widget/gbk/

There is a javascript to convert between gbk and unicode: **`which maps all the 21886 gbk Chinese chars to unicode`**

You can simply download the [javascript file](http://www.1kjs.com/lib/widget/gbk/UNIC-GBK.js) , include it and using :
**unicode to gbk:**

> `$URL.encode(unicode_string)`

**or gbk to unicode:**

> `$URL.decode(gbk_string)`

I tested it. It's working well on my web : zhuhaiyang.sinaapp.com/base64/index.html

which do base64 ency using pure javascript.

Comment: the link http://www.1kjs.com/lib/widget/gbk/ doesn't work anymore. Do you know of an alternate location?

Answer (score 1):

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/08/Easier-ArrayBuffer---String-conversion-with-the-Encoding-API

For chrome or firefox, you could use TextDecoder to decode any text to unicode:

```
function fetchAndDecode(file, encoding) {  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xhr.open('GET', file);  
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';  
    xhr.onload = function() {  
      if (this.status == 200) {  
        var dataView = new DataView(this.response);  
        var decoder = new TextDecoder(encoding);  
        var decodedString = decoder.decode(dataView);  
        console.info(decodedString);  
      } else {  
        console.error('Error while requesting', file, this);  
      }  
    };  
    xhr.send();  
  }

fetchAndDecode('gbkencoded.txt','gbk');
```