# How to convert the charset of HTTP GET data from GBK to UTF8 in Titanium Mobile?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, titanium, gbk

Websites in China always use gbk charset. I attempt to get the data from a site:

```
var url = "http://nga.178.com/thread.php?fid=7";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    // function called when the response data is available
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert(e.error + client.status);


        Ti.API.debug(client.responseText);
    },
    timeout : 50000 // in milliseconds
});
// Prepare the connection.
client.open("GET",url);
// Send the request.

client.send();
```

**but it response:**

```
[DEBUG] :  <title>ÌáÊ¾ÐÅÏ¢</title>
```

Comment: [Try this](http://freecode-freecode.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-gbkgb2312-and-utf-8-encoding.html), or [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211780/how-do-i-convert-gbk-to-utf8-with-pure-javascript)

Comment: @Josiah Hester,it seems no effect