# Does KDB+ HTML 5 websocket support UTF-8?

Tags: kdb

I am using https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/c/c.js for connecting HTML 5 websocket to KdB+ backend. I am facing an issue while sending Chinese characters from the backend. HTML charset is set for UTF-8 but still displays mess code rathan than correct characters. Same result when I print it in the web browser console. Dose c.js support UTF-8? How can I display Unicode characters correctly sent by KDB+ in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016.03.18, c.js should support (de)serialization of UTF8. The version [here](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/c/c.js) has the functions to do so.

More information on unicode charsets in kdb+ can be found [here](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/unicode/).

Comment: I am using the latest version of c.js (kx.com/q/c/c.js). But looks like it dose not (de)serialization of UTF8 correctly. For example, I did a test of sending Chinese characters from web browser to the kdb+ backend as below. 

<code>
in HTML js: 
var query = {func:"test",arg1:"你好"}; 
ws.send(serialize(query)); 

in kdb+ 
q)test:{show x} 
q)"\344\275\240\345\245\275" 
q)`char$"你好" "\304\343\272\303" 
</code>
As you can see "\344\275\240\345\245\275" is different from "\304\343\272\303". It looks like c.js uses a different method of (de)serialization of UTF8 from kdb+ dose.

Comment: Try printing (with -1@) the bytestream that you got from the browser - that should return the correct characters. There's more information here on how q treats unicode (http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/Unicode) which I'll edit into the original answer now, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

q)test:{show -1 x;}
q)test["\344\275\240\345\245\275"]
浣犲ソ

But 浣犲ソ is incorrect.  The bytestream should be "\304\343\272\303", which is corresponding to 你好. I don't know why "你好" sent from the browser serialized to "\344\275\240\345\245\275" rather than "\304\343\272\303" ?@paul

Comment: That's very strange - what happens if you serialize some ASCII text using c.js on the same HTML page and send that to the backend? Does that also become gibberish?

Comment: I find out the issue behind this. It was due to the miss match charset in KDB+ and HTML. KDB+ use gbk while c.js only support UTF-8 or UTF-16. Is there a way to transfer text from gbk to UTF-8 in kdb+?

Comment: I'm not aware of a kdb tool for it - since you're already using js, this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211780/how-do-i-convert-gbk-to-utf8-with-pure-javascript) might do the job for you.